# Change display properties

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, scale-mode

I have loaded 18.04 onto an old HP Pavilion 23", which doesn't have a display out. I have a USB display adapter, which is working well and I have a Samsung 32" TV that I'm using as a monitor.

When I go to screen display it shows the second monitor as a Samsung 7" and only allows the scale to be 100% or 200%.

I want to reduce the scale to about 50% but cannot find anywhere to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `xrandr` to set your monitor to 50% scale.  This is not permanently set so you would have to set it into a startup script if you want to keep it that way on every bootup.

First, get your currently connected monitors with the following command:

```
xrandr --current | grep -w connected
```

Example:

```
xrandr --current | grep -w connected
DVI-I-0 connected 1280x1024+1920+37 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
```

Pay attention to the monitor that you want to scale.  I am going to scale my second monitor that is attached to my DVI port.  *50% is .5*;  *100% is 1*  So we will run the following command to scale to 50%.

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --scale .5x.5
```

If you want it to change on every startup, add that command to your *Settings* -> *Session and Startup* but you might want the command like so to give it a slight delay at startup:

```
bash -c 'sleep 5; xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --scale .5x.5'
```

To set the monitor back at any time run the following:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --scale 1x1
```

Hope this helps!