# Mixed DPI setting on multiple monitors - Ubuntu 18.04 - how?

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.04, dpi, hdpi

I have been running Ubuntu 16.04 on my old Dell XPS 9530 with 4K screen, with an external regular DPI screen, and it has been almost OK. I can set scale individually on each screen - and set what screen new apps should scale for.

Now I have a new Dell XPS 9570, also with 4K screen, and I wanted to go for Ubuntu 18.04 (for the best drivers). And I discover to my surprise that I can only scale either 100% or 200% (or 300 / 400%) and the setting is applied for ALL attached screens, not pr screen as for Ubuntu 16.04. Is there some kind of way to make this available on a pr screen basis? I just looked at xrender, and it does not look like anything I want to touch. (My time is unfortunately hugely limited)

Other solutions I've found are setting the 4K display to 1K resolution. (I'd like to avoid this solution)

Am I the only one with a 4K laptop screen running an external regular-DPI monitor? (Perhaps this is my queue for a monitor-upgrade?)

Don't mean to sound negative wrt Ubuntu 18.04 - it looks great and I love using it - as long as I don't attach an external regular-DPI screen to it...

Comment: `xrandr` in a terminal window might be easier to use than you think.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1047778/231142

Comment: you're not the only one suffering from this regression in 18.04 :/

Comment: @Terrance - you are right - xrandr was not that hard - but it was hard to get it working correct. It did not apply the settings to only one of my screens, it affected both, even though I was following the instructions precisely. When all else fails - throw more money at the problem -> I have now purchased an external HDPI monitor which will arrive shortly. This will at least make my life better :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem as OP. I'll try to fix this one on my Dell XPS 15 9550 and get back if I'm able to configure xrandr correctly (I don't have the luxury to be able to buy a more expensive monitor)

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a command for your HI DPI monitor (if you execute it on the other monitor, your non hi DPI monitor will clog everything, rendering your desktop unusable but by keyboard and really grewsome stuff).

First detect the name in `xrandr` world of your monitor:

```
xrandr --current | grep -w connected
```

Example (on my Dell XPS 15 9550 with an external non HI DPI monitor and internal 4k):

```
$ xrandr --current | grep -w connected
eDP-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
```

For my machine I have run (eDP-1 is my 4k display of course):

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale .5x.5
```

If you really need your 4k monitor to have bigger stuff you can run:

xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale .4x.4

And for really short-sighted people (my case) you can run:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale .3x.3
```

For resetting (in case you push it so hard everything might break) do:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1
```

Made this comment following comment guide from [Change display properties](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047770/change-display-properties/1047778#1047778)

Answer (score 2):

See [Multi-monitor setup with xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110171/multi-monitor-setup-with-xrandr/1110215)

In particular, there was a long-standing bug in xserver to do with multiple scaling that is fixed with a HWE update that you will not get in 18.04 LTS through the normal update/upgrade mechanism - you have to run `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`.

Answer (score 2):

I have a perfectly working mixed DPI solution. Please take a look this post.
This commands works perfectly for 4k built-in monitor with 1080p external monitor setup.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1279438/1132543